# My Whiskey Liquid has waves

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I have recently started learning how to create liquids in Blender, and I've successfully created one, however, it was meant to be Whiskey so I wanted it to sit still in the glass as water does.

As you can see in the image, it looks like it has waves and even after prolonging the animation, it is never still. Any idea how I can get rid of this and make it seem more like whiskey in a glass would look IRL?

The first image is what I want the liquid to look like and the second one is my current render

[image]

[image]

Comment: So is there a fluid sim that fills the glass?

Comment: @AllenSimpson Yes, there is an inflow of the fluid filling the glass, and after I stop it there is like 100 more frames after it to make sure it has time to become still

Comment: Tell you what, I think I would just cut the video to a new angle, maybe show a few more frames of the liquid settling, and then another cut to the settled liquid where you've just exchanged this liquid for a static mesh.

Comment: So... unfortunately that's not technically an answer about how to do this in blender, but I'm also not sure it would ever be perfect otherwise.

Comment: Greg Zaal's blog has a really good post on liquid in glass containers that's worth a read.

Comment: I shall check out the blog thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example [image]

I assume you've tried playing with the Domain's viscosity and diffusion? If you need, you can animate these so that it behaves more like water as the glass fills and then turn more to honey for a while. [image]

My example will sort of freeze the liquid from about frame 30 to frame 80.  This might be useful for your need.

Or you may find that "playing" with these parameters adds stability to the liquid without animation of the parameters.